# Raycast can't find tagged gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

My `Raycast`rotates around the player and scans the 2D-Area. It should recognize another `Gameobject`, which is tagged as `Pick Up`, but `found` is always false.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Findway : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Player;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        transform.position = Player.transform.position;
    }

    RaycastHit hit;
    float[] distance = new float[360];
    int moveAngle = 0;
    bool found = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position = Player.transform.position;

        for (int iii = 0; iii < 360; iii++) 
        {
            Vector3 rayway = new Vector3 (Mathf.Cos(180 * iii / Mathf.PI), 0, Mathf.Sin(180 * iii / Mathf.PI));
            if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, rayway, out hit, 100f))
            {
                distance [iii] = hit.distance;
                //Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject);
                //Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.green);
                if (hit.collider.CompareTag ("Pick Up"))
                {
                    moveAngle = iii;
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dose your player moving around as well?

Comment: Yes, it should be a KI, that someday finds its way out of a labyrinth. So it moves, and the raycast, should be some kind of "radar" to scan the area.

Answer (score 3):

Use your ray cast out of the for loop , a good cpu  will not take long to run the iteration till 360 and using it in update will cause it to run infinite times causing more problems, always use divide and conquer , minimize the code , remove everything and just run the ray to check if its working without any rotation , then apply rotation ,do tell if it worked .Double Check if there is a object tagged as "Pick Up" . Also never use a for loop in update without an explicit condition to stop it like a bool otherwise it keeps on running .

Comment: just in case, remember that your targets must have an active collider too, just tag it right isn't enough for raycast...

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with the stationary raycast. After a night of good sleep, I changed the camera angle and realised, that the Raycast ist lower than the floating object. *facepalm*

Comment: If it helped can you please check it as answered